# How to map complex data property in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My model object looks like the following:

```
{ 
   "property1": "property1value", 
   "property2": [ 
       { 
           "propertyType": "type1", 
           "propertyValue": 10 
       },
       { 
           "propertyType": "type2", 
           "propertyValue": 20 
       }
   ]
}
```

In my markup I got a FORM and three INPUTs that should map to the VALUES of the following:

- property1
- property2 (type1)
- property2 (type2)

The first one is simple:

```
 <input v-model="property1" type="text"></input>
```

The problem with property2 is the complex structure AND the fact, that there can only be one type, not both!

Furthermore I want to post my form in a way, so that the properties match to my model structure.

How to solve this problem? I have no idea!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you set `property2` as `{type1: 10, type2: 20}` then bind with `v-model="property2.type1"`?

Comment: the model is fix and cannot be changed as it comes from an api :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments below, here is my updated answer.  The key is that you will need a method to locate the index of the propertyType and if the property type is not found you can use v-if to not show the field.  That v-if can be directly on the input field if it doesn't contain a label or other adjacent markup to be suppressed or for more flexibility that v-if can be on a template tag as I have done below.

```
 <div id="app">
    <input v-model="property1" type="text" /><br />
    <template v-if="getIndex('type1') >= 0">
        Type 1:<input v-model="property2[getIndex('type1')].propertyValue" type="text" /><br />
    </template>
    <template v-if="getIndex('type2') >= 0">
        Type 2: <input v-model="property2[getIndex('type2')].propertyValue" type="text" /><br />
    </template>
 </div>


 var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            "property1": "property1value",
            "property2": [
                {
                    "propertyType": "type1",
                    "propertyValue": 10
                },
                {
                    "propertyType": "type2",
                    "propertyValue": 20
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            getIndex: function (propType) {
                var i = 0;
                while (i < this.property2.length) {
                    if (this.property2[i].propertyType == propType) {
                        return i;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                return -1;
            }

        }
  });
```

Comment: actually i want only 3 inputs with mapping to property1value, property2.where(x=>x.propertyType=type1).propertyValue and property2. where(x=>x. propertyType=type2). propertyValue... and when i post all this stuff, it should be in structure of starting model... sorry, hard to describe my problem :(

Comment: Is it guaranteed that type1 and type2 exist in the property2 array?  And if not what should the two fields be bound to if their associated property type doesn't exist in the array?

Comment: it is possible, that property2 only has one item with propertytype=type2. then there should be no input, if possible...

Comment: will type1 always be at index 0 and type2 at index 1 if it exists?

Comment: no, thats one of my big problems... could be that type2 is at index 0... by the way, thanks for helping and asking the right questions :)

Comment: Can do.  It’s to hard too type the code in via my iPhone (I was trying) but I will update my answer to handle that on Monday when I get to the office.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if solves your issue.